# Centering UL inside div. Unknown error

Tags: css

I know there are plenty of turorials on how to center a UL inside a div. I've tried lots of them but cant get it to work. I assume I'm missing something. If anyone could look at it I would be grateful.

the site is  http://elvina-marin.se/
And I want to center the main menu somehow.

Cheers.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/209357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu isn't centered because the `li` are floating to `left`.

What you need to do here is to switch their display from `block` to `inline-block` and get rid of the `float`. That will make them behave as text and they will follow the alignment provided of the container (the `.gf-menu`).

```
.gf-menu {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.gf-menu > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* teaching ie7 and below to behave */
    zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set two classes for ul in your html: `<ul class="gf-menu l1 " >` and also left one blank space at the end. If you put space between words you set more classes to the tag.

Try calling your ul in CSS with one of your classes and set: `margin-left: 50%;`

Ex.:

```
.gf-menu
       {
      margin-left: 50%;
       }
```